# Is there a Rust crate to concisely and efficiently iterate values from the first column of a set of text files?

Tags: rust

This is efficient, but not concise.

Is there a crate that makes it concise?
(but not one that would load every file into memory)

```
use glob::glob;
use range_set_blaze::prelude::*;
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader},
};

fn main() {
    let mut all_exps = RangeSetBlaze::from_iter([0..=99_999_999]);

    // TODO: Is there a nicer Rust way to turn the first column of a set of files into an iterator?
    for path in glob("examples/cluster_file.*.tsv").unwrap() {
        let file = File::open(path.unwrap()).unwrap();

        let exp_nums: RangeSetBlaze<_> = BufReader::new(file)
            .lines()
            .skip(1)
            .map(|line| {
                line.unwrap()
                    .split('\t')
                    .next()
                    .unwrap()
                    .parse::<u32>()
                    .unwrap()
            })
            .collect();

        all_exps = all_exps - exp_nums;
    }
    println!("{all_exps}");
}
```

Comment: Honestly, that's pretty dang concise already. You could always move the implementation into a function to leave the rest of the logic uncluttered.

Comment: I second this. Also, you could split your mapping function into more steps, like `map(|l| l.unwrap().split('\t').next().unwrap()).map(|v| v.parse::<u32>().unwrap())` or more. This might look more clean depending on how exactly you split it up. Going further with a separate function, your main code could end up with 5 or 6 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For crates which might make things better I'd suggest [`csv`](https://docs.rs/csv/1.2.1/csv/), it's serde-compatible so might be you can deserialize to a 1-uple, ignoring the rest of the fields. I've never tested that though. Worst case scenario you can just deserialise to a full tuple / struct and access just the column / field you care about.

But you could also make your version a bit simpler if you don't mind *ignoring* invalid lines rather than panic-ing:

```rust
            .filter_map(|line| {
                line.ok()?
                    .split_once('\t')?
                    .0
                    .parse::<u32>().ok()
            })
```

- [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok) converts `Result<T, E>` to `Option<T>` so allows unifying results and options
- [`str::split_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_once) returns `(head, rest)`, so obviates the intermediate `next()` call if you just want the head
- because [`Iterator::filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) takes a callback which returns an `Option`, you can use `?` to short-circuit any `Option::None` to return immediately.